# How to call a member in Template argument?

Tags: c++, c++17

Hi everyone I'm required to use a struct as a derived class and template argument. Inside the struct, there is a member called "position".However, I couldn't find how to call it while it is being used as a template argument. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
struct Node
{
    std::vector<size_t>neighbors;      
};

template<typename NodeType>
class Graph
{
  public:
  void Initialize(size_t nodeCount);

  Node& GetNode(size_t index);
  const Node& GetNode(size_t index)const;

  private:
  std::vector<Node> mNodes;
};

  template<typename NodeType>
  inline void Graph<NodeType>::Initialize(size_t nodeCount)
{
  mNodes.resize(nodeCount);
}

  template<typename NodeType>
  inline Node & Graph<NodeType>::GetNode(size_t index)
{
  return mNodes[index];
}

  template<typename NodeType>
  inline const Node & Graph<NodeType>::GetNode(size_t index) const
{
  return mNodes[index];
}

//Inside the main cpp:

struct MapNode:public Node
{
  X::Math::Vector2 position{ 10.0f,10.0f };
};

 Graph<MapNode> graph;

void BuildGraph()
{
//....
  graph.Initialize(columns * rows);
  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
  {
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
    {
        int index = c + (r*columns);
        auto& node = graph.GetNode(index);
        // required to call node's position in here
     } 

    // ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That's all what my teacher coded and I should not change it...I know it is unusual.

Comment: If all of that should not be changed, then why are you asking how it should be changed? Perhaps you would like to use two code blocks -- one for the code that should not be changed (the context) and one for the code that you are asking about? More changes might be needed to make this a good question, but it would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

First, `mNodes` in `Graph` class should be a `std::vector` of `NodeType` and not just a `Node`. And the method `GetNode()` should returns a `NodeType` and not a `Node`. You define a class as a `template class` but you are not using at all your template definition.

```
template<typename NodeType>
class Graph
{
public:
    void Initialize(size_t nodeCount);

    NodeType& GetNode(size_t index);
    const NodeType& GetNode(size_t index)const;

private:
    std::vector<NodeType> mNodes;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for what Vuwox answered, I reconsidered the code and thought my teacher might make a mistake and Vuwox is right.